# Compare array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Create a method named ArrayCompare that compares between two arrays and returns a
boolean indicating whether they contain exactly the same elements or not. Its input should be
two integer arrays a and b. Its output should be a boolean, where it will return true if a and b
contain the same elements and false otherwise

Hello, I am new to c#, and I would like to know how this is done. I read up some documents and I can only come up with this.

```
    static bool ArrayCompare(int [] i , int [] j)
    {
        if (i.Length == j.Length)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < i.Length; o++)
            {

                //I am stuck here
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You can compare `i[o]` to `j[o]` at this place and check if they are identical.

Comment: I am not sure how to compare the arrays

Comment: `i[o]` and `j[o]` are just integers and can be complared using `==` or `!=`

Comment: Does the order matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 static bool ArrayCompare(int [] i , int [] j)
    {
        if (i.Length == j.Length)
        {
            for (int o = 0; o < i.Length; o++)
            {
                if(i[o]!=j[o])
                   return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You never return `true`

Comment: @KlausGütter my bad i edited

Comment: Note: alternatively you can also use the IEnumerable  extension method SequenceEqual, but in this case I feel that the homework need the algorithmic implementation to be provided

Answer (score 1):

You can check using the code blow

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 2 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 2 };

bool check = array1.SequenceEqual(array2);
```

Comment: while this does indeed work, I feel like the homework assignment is meant to have him write his own algorithm, instead of using an extension method

Comment: @MihaiC the question does not mention if this is an assignment or not. And unless otherwise specified, it is usually a good idea to use builtin functions when possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
static bool ArrayCompare(uint [] a, uint [] b)
{
    bool equal = true;
    if(a.Length== b.Length)
    {
        for(int i = 0,j=0; i < a.Length; ++i,++j)
        {
            if (a[i] != b[j])
            {
                   equal = false;
                   break;
           }
        }
    }
    return equal;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    static bool ArrayCompare(int[]a, int [] b)
    {

        if(a.Length == b.Length)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] == b[i])
                {
                    if(a[a.Length - 1] == b[b.Length - 1])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
                   
            }
        }

        return false;

    }
```

This method takes in two int arrays as parameters, we are then checking to first make sure that both the arrays are the same length before we loop. In the for loop we are checking to make sure that if the current index of the first array is the same as the current index of the second array is the same. If it is, we get the to last index of both arrays, and if the same we return true, if the indexes are not the same we return false. We can then create two arrays and console out the method with the two arrays as parameters.

Comment: So, `{1, 2, 3}` and `{1, 4, 3 }` would be considered identical? I'm not sure what this is trying to do, but I'm fairly sure it is incorrect.

Comment: @JonasH My bad, will fix my code while I wait for your answer

Comment: this is wrong. it will return true even if the arrays are not equal

Comment: @MihaiC Yeah I know that, as already pointed out,  no need to say again? I have realized my mistake